# Kartograph - converted svg not the same as before

Tags: qgis, python, svg, natural-earth

I'm using the following script to convert a map from [NaturalEarthData](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/110m-admin-0-countries/). But the result is very sobering. It seems like something went wrong with the scaling, but I got no errors when executing the script. What am I doing wrong??

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kartograph import Kartograph
K = Kartograph()

config = {
    "layers": {
        "mylayer": {
            "src": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp",
            "charset": "utf-8",
            "attributes": "all"
        }
    }, 
}

K.generate(config, outfile='world.svg')
```

Comment: What was the result before?

Comment: This map looks completely bent. Don't you see it?

Comment: How else should it look like?

Comment: @kwoxer http://imgur.com/sI1vGET

Comment: Well I have no idea. You are using basic mechanics and they should work indeed. But when I tried out Kartograph I had some serious trouble as well. I'm now using d3 with topojson. And that is pretty awesome but a little bit more difficult for sure. Maybe you can use other frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

Change your config to say:

```
config = {
    "layers": {
        "mylayer": {
            "src": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp",
            "charset": "utf-8",
            "attributes": "all"
        }
    }, 
  "proj": {
    "id": "lonlat"
  }
}
```

That's the code for the equirectangular projection. Other codes found [here](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py/blob/master/kartograph/proj/__init__.py).